# for which blackberry types/resolution develop apps?

Tags: blackberry, types, resolution

i am new to Blackberry apps development, and see that there are lot of different resolutions of display on different Blackberry types.

is there some survey which types are most used ? which resolutions is good to support ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to worry so much about which specific devices you will support (unless you need specific features like touch capability).  However, you do want to consider which OS version(s) to target to get the right combination of audience and feature set.

RIM provides "[Choosing a target OS](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/choosingtargetos.jsp)" with lots of good data to at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to worry about the resolution of the blackberry Mobile Screens... We can programmitically give the resolution by checking the series of the blackberry devices... 
Do you want the java code to find out the series of the blackberry mobile devices

Comment: thats not point of my question. if you look into app store, each app has different list of supported devices. i asked which blackberry devices is good to support and which not and why.

Answer (score 0):

The link that @Scott W provided is a good start in deciding which OS to support. Let me dig into this a little further, assuming you are creating an app for consumption by non-Enterprise users (delivery through App World);

- As of March, devices running pre-5.0 OSs make up less than 20% of the total, and for paid apps, this figure is 10%.
- By percentage, paid apps are consumed by those with newer devices than for free apps, for every OS across the board.

Keeping all this in mind, I recommend the following to you;

- Don't consider targeting pre-5.0 devices, it's a waste of your time (I know, I've done this before).
- Consider the time it will take you to create an app and release it (anywhere between 2 to 6 months) and imagine what the BB OS market share will look like (OS 7 will be released by then).
- Start developing targeting BB OS 5.0, and if you encounter an issue whereby OS 6 provides functionality you need that is not available in 5.0 (you'll have to implement your own solution), seriously consider dropping 5.0 support or not including such feature in your 5.0 build.
- If your core competencies are in Java, stick with that, otherwise, seriously consider developing in WebWorks, as that has the advantage of running on PlayBook and you'll have reusable code if you're building a mobile website.

As for devices, the Curve series is easily the most popular amongst BlackBerry's devices (as it's cheap to buy). However, if you write your UI code to be mindful of container sizes, your interface could look the same on all devices (if you want it to be).